# How to position a LabelFrame which include a button and it is inside of a Frame - Using tkinter in Python

Tags: python, tkinter, widget, label, frame

I've been trying to position my `LabelFrame` which is inside of a `Frame` and it includes 2 buttons. I want to place it at the bottom right corner of the screen... I thought to use width/height/x/y but that it will only apply for that current screen that I'm working with! So I've end up to the `.grid` and `place()` but because I'm new to tkinter I don't know how to use... I've search everywhere and to be honest it didn't help me at all, so bellow you will find a photo of want I want to look like and my code of what I wrote so far that didn't lead me anywhere ↓

layout: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IpJQJ.png

►**CODE**◄

```py
#creating the frames ↓
    upFrame = Frame(window, bg='blue')
    upFrame.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='n')
    midFrame = Frame(window, bg='red')
    midFrame.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky='nesw')
    bottomFrame = Frame(window, bg='yellow')
    bottomFrame.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky='s')
    
    window.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)
    window.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    window.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight = 1,)
    
    #Creating the label time
    label_time = LabelFrame(bottomFrame, pady= 0, padx= 5, bg='lightgray')
    label_time.pack(anchor='se')
    
    #Creating the button
    btn1 = Button(label_time, text = "Click Me", pady= 10, height= "1", width= "20")
    btn1.pack(side= LEFT)

    btn2 = Button(label_time, text = "Or Me...", pady= 10, height= "1", width= "20")
    btn2.pack(side= RIGHT)
```

Comment: Why do you put the top, middle and bottom frames at the same cell (row=1, column=0)?

Comment: I don't remeber if I mentioned that I'm new to tk so that's why... By the way thanks all the times I was thinking that my mistake is on the `.grid` but no... So thanks!